# How to resize JLabel ImageIcon?

Tags: java, image, swing

I'm making a Java Swing application that has the following layout ([`MigLayout`](http://www.miglayout.com/)):

```
[icon][icon][icon][....]
where icon = jlabel and the user can add more icons
```

When the user adds or removes icons, the others should shrink or grow.

My question is really straightforward: I have a `JLabel` which contains an `ImageIcon`; how can I resize this icon?

Comment: `.... following layout.` is FlowLayout ??? (defalut Layout is there isn't defined anything) http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html, are you know http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Resizing the icon is not straightforward. You need to use Java's graphics 2D to scale the image. The first parameter is a Image class which you can easily get from `ImageIcon` class. You can use `ImageIcon` class to load your image file and then simply call getter method to get the image.

```
private Image getScaledImage(Image srcImg, int w, int h){
    BufferedImage resizedImg = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g2 = resizedImg.createGraphics();

    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    g2.drawImage(srcImg, 0, 0, w, h, null);
    g2.dispose();

    return resizedImg;
}
```

Answer (score 120):

Try this :

```
ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("./img/imageName.png"); // load the image to a imageIcon
Image image = imageIcon.getImage(); // transform it 
Image newimg = image.getScaledInstance(120, 120,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH); // scale it the smooth way  
imageIcon = new ImageIcon(newimg);  // transform it back
```

(found it [here](http://www.nullpointer.at/2011/08/21/java-code-snippets-howto-resize-an-imageicon/#comment-11870))

Answer (score 42):

And what about it?:

```
ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("icon.png").getImage().getScaledInstance(20, 20, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
label.setIcon(imageIcon);
```

From: [Resize a picture to fit a JLabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343098/resize-a-picture-to-fit-a-jlabel/32885963#32885963)

Answer (score 10):

This will keep the right aspect ratio.

```
    public ImageIcon scaleImage(ImageIcon icon, int w, int h)
    {
        int nw = icon.getIconWidth();
        int nh = icon.getIconHeight();

        if(icon.getIconWidth() > w)
        {
          nw = w;
          nh = (nw * icon.getIconHeight()) / icon.getIconWidth();
        }

        if(nh > h)
        {
          nh = h;
          nw = (icon.getIconWidth() * nh) / icon.getIconHeight();
        }

        return new ImageIcon(icon.getImage().getScaledInstance(nw, nh, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

One (quick & dirty) way to resize images it to use HTML & specify the new size in the image element.  This even works for animated images with transparency.

Answer (score 3):

I agree this code works, to size an ImageIcon from a file for display while keeping the aspect ratio I have used the below.

```
/*
 * source File of image, maxHeight pixels of height available, maxWidth pixels of width available
 * @return an ImageIcon for adding to a label
 */


public ImageIcon rescaleImage(File source,int maxHeight, int maxWidth)
{
    int newHeight = 0, newWidth = 0;        // Variables for the new height and width
    int priorHeight = 0, priorWidth = 0;
    BufferedImage image = null;
    ImageIcon sizeImage;

    try {
            image = ImageIO.read(source);        // get the image
    } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Picture upload attempted & failed");
    }

    sizeImage = new ImageIcon(image);

    if(sizeImage != null)
    {
        priorHeight = sizeImage.getIconHeight(); 
        priorWidth = sizeImage.getIconWidth();
    }

    // Calculate the correct new height and width
    if((float)priorHeight/(float)priorWidth > (float)maxHeight/(float)maxWidth)
    {
        newHeight = maxHeight;
        newWidth = (int)(((float)priorWidth/(float)priorHeight)*(float)newHeight);
    }
    else 
    {
        newWidth = maxWidth;
        newHeight = (int)(((float)priorHeight/(float)priorWidth)*(float)newWidth);
    }


    // Resize the image

    // 1. Create a new Buffered Image and Graphic2D object
    BufferedImage resizedImg = new BufferedImage(newWidth, newHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g2 = resizedImg.createGraphics();

    // 2. Use the Graphic object to draw a new image to the image in the buffer
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight, null);
    g2.dispose();

    // 3. Convert the buffered image into an ImageIcon for return
    return (new ImageIcon(resizedImg));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that there is a minor edit to this fix from trolologuy on the last line of code, you will need to implement a new ImageIcon to get the code to compile properly (Yes I know this is 10 years ago).  I found this to be an easy fix for a one off issue, but Suken Shah and Mr. Polywhirl have a better fix overall.

```
ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("./img/imageName.png"); // assign image to a new ImageIcon
Image image = imageIcon.getImage(); // transform it 
Image newimg = image.getScaledInstance(120, 120,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH); // scale it smoothly  
ImageIcon newImageIcon = new ImageIcon(newimg);  // assign to a new ImageIcon instance
```