# Make a Java JLabel Icon Resizeable

Tags: java, swing, resize, jlabel, java-2d

How does one resize an image that will be placed in a JLabel?

```
ImageIcon icon = ImageIcon("img.gif");

JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
```

Comment: Are you attached to `JLabel`?  If not, check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548808/scale-the-imageicon-automatically-to-label-size/14553003#14553003)

Comment: Im not attached to it but it has to be simpler than a few lines.. right??

Comment: Are you looking for a fixed size image, or do you want the Icon to dynamically resize as space is available? If it's the latter the check out [Stretch Icon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/).

Comment: You should be resizing the image and then let the label size itself based on the image. You can use image.getScaledImage(...) for the different size images. http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/23992-how-resize-images-fit-jlabel.html . A JLabel or JButton computes its preferred size according to is icon and/or text. If you need an image size that depends on the size of the component it is displayed in, custom painting may be a better option. http://www.java-forums.org/awt-swing/35208-help-how-auto-resize-image-icon-fit-jlabel.html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714045/how-to-resize-jlabel-

Comment: Not really.  You need to jump through a few hoops to get the size of the icon to the size you want, as described in the link I provided...