# Resizing JLabel ImageIcon with HTML

Tags: java, html, swing, jlabel, imageicon

So I looked through [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714045/how-to-resize-jlabel-imageicon) and saw the suggestion of using HTML for resizing.

I've been going through the Oracle website but it only provided example for text customization in JLabels using HTML. Can I get an example of a `JLabel` with HTML parameters?

Comment: Do you mean something like `label.setText("<html><img width=200 height=200 src=..."></html>");`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This basically requires you to have a `URL` reference to the image in question.  This is quite easy to achieve if the image is an embedded resource (as demonstrated below), but you should be able to generate a `URL` from file using `File#getURI#toURL`

[image]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class HTMLLabel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new HTMLLabel();
    }

    public HTMLLabel() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                URL url = getClass().getResource("/Chicken.png");
                System.out.println(url);

                JLabel perLabel = new JLabel("<html><img width=125 height=125 src=" + url + "></html>");
                JLabel orgLabel = new JLabel("<html><img src=" + url + "></html>");

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

                GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

                frame.add(orgLabel, gbc);
                frame.add(perLabel, gbc);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

It should be noted that scaling is pretty redumentry.  I would, personally, avoid it and simple devise some kind of `ImagePane` that had better scaling capabilities, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548808/scale-the-imageicon-automatically-to-label-size/14553003#14553003)

Comment: Thank you for the complete example. Would your recommendation work on animated transparent gifs also?

Comment: You can to ask about animated gifs :P

Comment: You could try having a look at something like [Gif4J](http://www.gif4j.com/java-gif4j-pro-gif-image-transform.htm), I've not used it personally...

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for all the suggestions. MadProgrammer strikes again!

Comment: Let me know how you go with that library, if it's any good or not ;)