# Change size JLabel (ImageIcon) on Java

Tags: java, swing, scale, jlabel, imageicon

I have this code:

http://pastebin.com/N7XnK8XH

The result is a large display panel, but the picture still is small, does not scale I've tried everything

Please help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resize Jlabel ImageIcon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714045/how-to-resize-jlabel-imageicon)

Comment: btw copy your code into the description of SOF not external links

Answer (score 0):

> but the picture still is small, does not scale

Try Darryl's [Stretch Icon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/) for dynamic scaling of the Icon to fill the space available to the JLabel.