# Can I make a JLabel with an icon image resizeable?

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel, imageicon

Just like we can resize a `JFrame` I'd like to show an image on a frame. **I'd like to be it resizeable** so when I resize **the image** should be resized.

How could I do this?

```
try {
    myPicture = ImageIO.read(f);
    picLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(myPicture));
    panel.add(picLabel);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I added the label (with the image) to a `JPanel` and the panel is added to the frame.

Comment: [Custom painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) the image seems the best approach for something like this. Forget the `ImageIcon` and `JLabel` - instead paint the image directly in a `JPanel` & adjust the size & position as needed when painting it to the graphics.

Answer (score 0):

`ImageIcons` are always resizeable. Try converting it to an `image`, resizing it, convert it back to an `ImageIcon`, and then reapplying it (of course do this when you want to resize it).

```
Image myScaledPicture = myPicture.getImage().getScaledInstance(newWidth, newHeight, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
picLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(myScaledPicture);
```

More info here: [How to resize JLabel ImageIcon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714045/how-to-resize-jlabel-imageicon)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Stretch Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/).

It can be used in any component that can paint an Icon and the image will scale as the component is resized.

It is reusable code so you don't have to do custom painting all the time.