# Java swing JButton/JLabel: icons are not displayed in their original size

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlabel, imageicon

I have png icons and use them as icons in `JButton` / `JLabel`.
The problem is that the image displayed at runtime is larger than the original icon, and because of this resizing, it's super ugly.

Here is an example:
Original icon (left) and how it's rendered in the `JButton` (right)

[image: original icon (left) and how it's rendered in the JButton (right)]

The source code for this minimal example is simply:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String... args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setBounds(0, 0, 120, 80);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("icon.png");
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JButton("Test", icon));
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Is this expected? If not, how can I avoid this? I tried many things around forcing the size of the image, the button, etc. but could not get a proper image displayed.

I have tested with icons of various sizes: 16x16, 17x17, 18x18, 19x19, 20x20, and each time the icon displayed on the `JButton` is a bit larger than the original which makes it look ugly:

[image: original icons sizes vs icons on JButton]

Thank you!

Cheers.

Comment: Any chance you could post a link to `icon.png` so that I can try to reproduce what you claim to be seeing?

Comment: Have you tried scaling the image yourself like [shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18335435/11441011)?

Comment: Thanks Abra. The same happens with absolutely any icon. Tried the same code using an icon from the following URL:
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(new URL("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/6x16-free-application-icons/16/Help.png"));
The same issue occurred: icon is slightly bigger and all ugly.

Comment: Thanks Maloomeister: yes I tried. The icon is 16x16 and I actually want it to be displayed with its original size of 16x16. I tried resizing to 16x16 (although it should not be required), and the icon is still displayed slightly bigger.

Answer (score 4):

This is because you are using Windows scaling. The entire component is scaled, both the icon and the text.

You could turn the scaling of the Icon off by using a wrapper Icon:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import javax.swing.*;


public class NoScalingIcon implements Icon
{
    private Icon icon;

    public NoScalingIcon(Icon icon)
    {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public int getIconWidth()
    {
        return icon.getIconWidth();
    }

    public int getIconHeight()
    {
        return icon.getIconHeight();
    }

    public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y)
    {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();

        AffineTransform at = g2d.getTransform();

        int scaleX = (int)(x * at.getScaleX());
        int scaleY = (int)(y * at.getScaleY());

        int offsetX = (int)(icon.getIconWidth() * (at.getScaleX() - 1) / 2);
        int offsetY = (int)(icon.getIconHeight() * (at.getScaleY() - 1) / 2);

        int locationX = scaleX + offsetX;
        int locationY = scaleY + offsetY;

        AffineTransform scaled = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(1.0 / at.getScaleX(), 1.0 / at.getScaleY());
        at.concatenate( scaled );
        g2d.setTransform( at );

        icon.paintIcon(c, g2d, locationX, locationY);

        g2d.dispose();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JButton button = new JButton( "Button" );
        NoScalingIcon icon = new NoScalingIcon( new ImageIcon("box.jpg") );
        button.setIcon( icon );

        JPanel panel = new JPanel( );
        panel.add( button );

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(panel);
        f.setSize(200, 200);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

1. The scaling adjustment will position the Icon at the top/left of the button area.
2. The offset adjustment will then attempt to center the Icon in the scaled icon painting area.
3. Using the default transform will have a scaling factor of 0 for the Icon.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all.
The problem was the default scaling factor (which was 1.25).
As I want to be fully in control of the size independently from DPI, I solved my issue by forcing the scaling factor to 1.0.

[This answer was helpful](https://superuser.com/a/1194728)

So, either pass to the command line

```
-Dsun.java2d.uiScale=1.0,
```

or set it programmatically

```
System.setProperty("sun.java2d.uiScale", "1.0")
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the source code for the [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon-java.lang.String-) of class `ImageIcon` that takes a string parameter. It uses class `java.awt.Toolkit` to create the image from the file. This made me think that it must be doing some scaling. So I thought of creating the icon differently. `ImageIcon` has another [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon-java.awt.Image-) that takes an `Image` parameter. So I created a `BufferedImage` from the file and then used that image to create an `ImageIcon`. The `BufferedImage` is not scaled.

Note that your link to the icon file didn't work for me so I just downloaded a different 16x16 icon.

```java
java.awt.image.BufferedImage img = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(new java.io.File("cellphon.png"));
javax.swing.Icon ico = new javax.swing.ImageIcon(img);
javax.swing.JButton button = new javax.swing.JButton("Test", ico);
```