# How can I resize an image from a URL into a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jlabel

```
try {
    addImage(bodyPanel1, "https://sneakernews.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/jordan-1-black-mocha-555088-105-2.jpg");
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}


private void addImage(JPanel cp, String url) throws MalformedURLException{
    cp.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(new URL(url))));
}
```

So I am trying to insert the image using a URL and then have it resize to the size of the bodypanel but whenever i try to run it the image doesnt scale itself. I have the entire bodypanel in a grid layout (3 row, 2 columns) and want to add an image to fit the entire size of one of the grid boxes.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49XBU.png)

Comment: Use ImageIO to retrieve the image, scale the image, and convert the scaled image to an ImageIcon when creating the JLabel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code I found ([Link to code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18335435/13187363) | [Link to the guy who originally found this code](http://www.nullpointer.at/2011/08/21/java-code-snippets-howto-resize-an-imageicon/#comment-11870)):

```
ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(new URL(url)); // load the image to a imageIcon
Image image = imageIcon.getImage(); // transform it 
Image newimg = image.getScaledInstance(120, 120,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH); // scale it the smooth way  
imageIcon = new ImageIcon(newimg);
cp.add(new JLabel(imageIcon));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    ImageIcon originalIcon = new ImageIcon("slovakia.png");
    JLabel originalLabel = new JLabel(originalIcon);

    int width = originalIcon.getIconWidth() / 2;
    int height = originalIcon.getIconHeight() / 2;

    Image scaled = scaleImage(originalIcon.getImage(), width, height);

    ImageIcon scaledIcon = new ImageIcon(scaled);

    JLabel newLabel = new JLabel(scaledIcon);
```